# How to use ExtJS modern Grid Row expander Plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs6-modern

How to use the grid row expander plugin used in Kitchensink?. Which is not working when we give the itemConfig body tag and plugin list.

Its working only after we mention the column externally like below. Also the row number cell is not displaying the digits more than one, even after setting width its not working.

```
columns: [{
        //expander is not displayed without adding this expander column
        text: '',
        width: 50,
        resizable: false,
        hideable: false,
        sortable: false,
        editable: false,
        ignore: true,
        ignoreExport: true,


        cell: {
            xtype: 'expandercell',
        }
    },{
....
}]
```

There is no Docx for using
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/m...wExpander.html

Find the fiddle
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qnr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are specifying the grid configs, the `plugins` has to be specified under the columns.

Check this fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qov it's the same as yours only the plugins are put under the columns.

However this is not the general approach in ExtJS, usually it should not matter where you specify the configs but it seems necessary for the `rowexpander`.

The second issue with the rownumberer it looks like a bug. When you put more than 100 it will be OK again. Also when you use Triton theme it's OK. It looks like the width of the row is incorrectly counted when using Material theme.